# How can I reference a local file to be used in a Supabase migration?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

Using Supabase locally, how can I reference a local `.sql` file to be used within a Supabase migration file?

For example:

This is my directory structure:

```
- db
  - supabase
   - types
    - custom_type.sql
   - migrations
    - some_timestamp_migration.sql
```

Then within my `some_timestamp_migration.sql`, if I tried to reference the `custom_type.sql` using:

```sql
\i db/supabase/custom_type.sql
```

I'm not sure if this usage is incorrect or it's an issue with using local Supabase migration commands.

```
supabase migration up
```

This results in:
`Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" (SQLSTATE 42601)`

I could of course copy & paste the contents of these files directly to the migrations but I don't think that would be very good DX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unfortuately supabase doesn't support `\i` directives like postgresql cmd client does. A way to get around this would be to temporarily concatenate your SQL files using a command like `cat` and then migrate that up.

let's take your two sql scripts for example-

```bash
cat db/supabase/custom_type.sql db/supabase/migrations/some_timestamp_migration.sql > combined_migration.sql
supabase migration up
```

this would make a new sql that combines the content of the two and push it up for migration. However, there are some nice thirdparty's that does this, like flyway - do check out [Migrate - Flyway](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/command-line-migrate-184127414.html) - if you want it more DX friendly